# When to use which library? azure-mobile-apps-js-client and cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps

Tags: node.js, cordova, azure-mobile-services

I am confused about the following two Microsoft Azure libraries:

- azure-mobile-apps-js-client
- cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps

Does anybody know which one to use when? Or what are the advantages of one over other?

From their names, it appears that the "azure-mobile-apps-js-client" will not contain cordova features while  "cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps" does. Is that the only difference?

My previous questions were more generic. So adding some more comments to give you more context on why I have those questions.

I was building an Ionic 2 app some time back then stopped it for a couple of months. Now getting back on Ionic app and see this new JS Client library (azure-mobile-apps-js-client) around. My Ionic 2 app is basically going to invoke/call REST endpoints implemented in **Azure Mobile App backend** developed using Node.js.

Last time when I was developing it by following Microsoft documentation for Azure Mobile Apps, I tried to use "cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps" as per the docs.

Now I see this new library (azure-mobile-apps-js-client).

And therefore I have confusion on which one really to use. If anybody has a link that describes both of these libraries in detail and their differences then please do share the link. It would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The cordova plugin is the JS client wrapped in a plugin.  Use whichever is more convenient for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Adrian.

Comment: I was building an Ionic app some time back then stopped it for a couple of months. Now getting back on Ionic app and see this new JS Client library (azure-mobile-apps-js-client) around. I know it's too much to ask for a detailed answer on what are differences, advantages of one over other, etc. By any chance, do you have or know of a link that would provide detailed information/differences about both of these libraries? In my case, my Ionic 2 app is going to invoke/call REST endpoints implemented in Azure Mobile App backend developed using Node.js. Note sure which library to use.

Comment: Both of them use the exactly same source code. Refer [Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client) for more details about the Cordova plugin.